# How does recursive inheritance work ? class PersonInfoBuilder<SELF> : PersonBuilder where SELF : PersonInfoBuilder<SELF>

Tags: c#, generics

This seems like a chicken and an egg problem to me.

```
class PersonInfoBuilder<SELF> : PersonBuilder 
where SELF : PersonInfoBuilder<SELF>
```

// PersonBuilder is an abstract class in this example.
How does `PersonInfoBuilder<SELF> : PersonBuilder`
which has the constrains of `SELF : PersonInfoBuiler<SELF>`

Comment: That does not even compile... you can't put a generic constraint on a non generic class definition.

Comment: @InBetween my bad, this is the actual code. did my conversion wrongly.

Comment: Edited it so that the source code is displayed correctly

Comment: Read on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance to `PersonBuilder` is just noise, your question is about this pattern:

```
class PersonInfoBuilder<SELF> where SELF : PersonInfoBuilder<SELF>
```

Let's change the names and make a convoluted example that makes use of the pattern:

```
abstract class CompatibleAnimal<T>  where T: CompatibleAnimal<T>
{
    public abstract CompatibleAnimal<T> BreedWith(T t);
}

abstract class Equine: CompatibleAnimal<Equine> 
{
    public override abstract CompatibleAnimal<Equine> BreedWith(Equine t);
}

class Mule: Equine {
    public override CompatibleAnimal<Equine> BreedWith(Equine t)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override string ToString() => "mules";
}

class Horse: Equine {
    public override CompatibleAnimal<Equine> BreedWith(Equine t)
    {
        if (t is Donkey)
            return new Mule();
        if (t is Horse)
            return new Horse();
        return null;
    }

    public override string ToString() => "horses";
}

class Donkey: Equine
{
    public override CompatibleAnimal<Equine> BreedWith(Equine t)
    {
        if (t is Donkey)
            return new Donkey();
        if (t is Horse)
            return new Mule();
        return null;
    }

    public override string ToString() => "donkeys";
}
```

And now:

```
public static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross horses with horses you get {
            new Horse().BreedWith(new Horse())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
     Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross donkeys with donkeys you get {
            new Donkey().BreedWith(new Donkey())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
      Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross horses with donkeys you get {
            new Horse().BreedWith(new Donkey())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
     Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross mules with mules you get {
            new Mule().BreedWith(new Mule())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
     Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross mules with donkeys you get {
            new Mule().BreedWith(new Donkey())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
              Console.WriteLine(
        $@"If you cross mules with horses you get {
            new Mule().BreedWith(new Horse())?.ToString() ?? "nothing"}");
}
```

And of course, if you create a similar class hierarchy for canines, the type system won't allow you to accidentally breed an equine with a canine, which seems like a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @InBetween for your long and detailed answer.